# C - preprocessors multiple macros

Tags: c, gcc, macros, conditional-statements, preprocessor-directive

Gcc 4.8.x - 4.9.x

Hello,

I would like to merge multiple macros in a `#ifdef` directive, e.g :

```
#ifdef PLOT || GRAPH
..mycode..
#endif
```

But it doesn't work.

How may I achieve this ?

This is not an option :

```
#ifdef PLOT
#ifdef GRAPH
..mycode..
#endif
#endif
```

because if plot is defined and not graph, lost.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this syntax:

```
#if defined(PLOT) || defined(GRAPH)
```